# Adding my custom post type as its own menu item in Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently building a Website for a company with multiple locations. Using the Wordpress Multi-site system I have everything functioning as needed. I now have created an area for Location Information. This is things like address, phone, etc. I am using ACF to create this area. There is a custom post type I created but it is set up like any other post. It says Location Information with a submenu, add new, edit, quick edit, etc. I need the one I created. post.php?post=41 to be added directly to the menu. So when a location owner clicks on it they go right to the area to edit the screen. I do not need the add new, edit stuff to be accessible. How do I get it there? [image: Image of what I need for menu placement]

Answer (score 0):

You can select custom post type from screen option menu on top of the menu edit page.

Comment: That does really do what I need. I need to take that post_id out of that area and place it directly into the dashboard menu

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario in brief?

Comment: I need that custom post=41 to be in the main menu of the dashboard. So the user doesnt have to click Location Information once, and then location information again to get to my post.